# how do I link the bugs to the src file when using the findbugs ant task?

Tags: findbugs

how do I link the bugs to the src file when using the findbugs ant task?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sourcePath`, an optional nested element which specifies a source directory path containing source files used to compile the Java code being analyzed. By specifying a source path, any generated XML bug output will have complete source information, which allows later viewing in the GUI.

```xml
<target name="findbugs">
  <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" output="xml" outputFile="findbugs_report.xml">
    <auxClasspath path="${basedir}/lib" />
      <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/java" />
      <class location="${basedir}/bin" />
   </findbugs>
</target>
```